# How to use an array of values from PHP in the 'IN' clause of mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

```
//get all id's of ur friend that has installed your application
 $friend_pics=$facebook->api( array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid   IN(SELECT uid2 from friend WHERE uid1='$user') AND is_app_user = 1" ) ); // this query work fine
//your top10 friends in app
$result="SELECT * FROM fb_user WHERE user_id IN($friend_pics) ORDER BY oldscore DESC LIMIT 0,10";
db_execute($result);
```

i want to retrive ten top scorer from my database stored in oldscore but in my second query the array name $friend_pics is not working i guess,plz help me thanks

Comment: You'll need to post more of your code, and / or your db schema. There could be a lot of problems here. This isn't enough information.

Comment: Hopefully one of the placeholder-enabled access methods (mysqli or pdo) support a construct like this (they should generally be used anyway).

Answer (score 3):

There is no native support for that. Even the bound parameter APIs do not allow to use arrays for `IN` clauses. You have to construct the query with some helper code:

```
$friend_pics = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $friend_pics);
$friend_pics = "'" . implode("', '", $friend_pics) . "'";
"SELECT * WHERE user_id IN ($friend_pics)              "
```

A simpler alternative would be mysqls [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) however:

```
$friend_pics = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(",", $friend_pics));
"SELECT * FROM fb_user WHERE find_in_set(user_id,'$friend_pics')     "
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you convert that array into a string of long list of your values unless array is huge size.

```
    $ids    = array(2, 4, 6, 8);
$params = implode(",", array_fill(0, count($ids), "?"));

    $result="SELECT * FROM fb_user WHERE user_id IN($params) ORDER BY oldscore DESC LIMIT 0,10";
db_execute($result);
```

Comment: What should it do can i get wt i want?

Comment: $friendsAp = implode(",",$friendpics); i already did this but not working

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home5/roohware/

Comment: wt should i put in "?" i in my array i have now 30 ids how to put it in "?" thanking u in anticipation

Comment: Did you try what mario told? "?" is just for what value to fill in array. Somehow I feel $result is not getting any values in result of the query you are executing.

Comment: yep i tried but its giving "access denied for user"xxxxxxx n blaw blaw blaw i guess i havent include mysql_real_escape_string in my connection m i rite?

Comment: Probably problem with your mysql ..you don't need different access for mysql_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 1):

`$friend_pics` should be a string containing a comma separated list i.e. "1, 2, 3, 4". If it is not, then your second query will always fail.

Comment: this work perfectly$friend_pics=$facebook->api( array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid   IN(SELECT uid2 from friend WHERE uid1='$user') AND is_app_user = 1" ) );foreach($friend_pics as $status_a) {
        $status_sql[] = '\''.$status_a['uid'].'\'';
    }
    $status = implode(',',$status_sql);$result=  "SELECT * FROM fb_user WHERE user_id IN($status) ORDER BY oldscore DESC LIMIT 0,10";
     db_execute($result); this is damn rite thaks 4 ur help