# Mysql Query from an array

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL query using an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101662/mysql-query-using-an-array)
>   [How to use an array of values from PHP in the 'IN' clause of mysql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207699/how-to-use-an-array-of-values-from-php-in-the-in-clause-of-mysql-query)

from a Post form i have an array like that

```
Array
(
    [userid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4e8329e97231c
            [1] => 4e64b47849318
            [2] => 4e4e415a30000
        )

)
```

i am little struggle to retrieve the users data from mysql from this array

that should be something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM user_detail WHERE user_id='4e64b47849318' OR user_id='4e8329e97231c' OR user_id='4e4e415a30000'
```

Comment: So.. what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Various answers here are reasonable, just make sure you're terrified of SQL injection, and deal with it appropriately.

Comment: Looks like bad day for all answerer.

Comment: What is happening with the downvotes on all answers ? :O

Comment: You've not explicitly asked anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
$yourArray = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $yourArray);

$query = "SELECT * FROM user_detail WHERE user_id='";
$query .= implode($yourArray, "' OR user_id='");
$query .= "'";
```

Or indeed, use the SQL `IN` keyword:

```
$yourArray = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $yourArray);

$query = "SELECT * FROM user_detail WHERE user_id IN ('";
$query .= implode($yourArray, "','");
$query .= "')";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$clean_userid = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $arr['userid'])
$str_user_id = "'" . implode("', '", $clean_userid ) . "'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_detail WHERE user_id IN ( $str_user_id )";
```

Comment: It would probably be good practice to use `array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $arr['userid'])` instead of `$arr['userid']`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MySQL `IN` operator nicely here, it works like "OR" but you can essentially give it a list.

```
$user_id_string = implode(',', $array['userid']);
```

You now have a comma separated string of your user_id's.

Now query something like:

```
SELECT * FROM user_detail WHERE user_id IN ($user_id_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

$criteria = "'".implode("','",$userID)."'";

$sql = "select * from user_detail where user_id in ($criteria)";

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
"SELECT * FROM user_detail
WHERE user_id IN ('". implode("','", $array['userid'])."')"
```

Comment: ALL answers were downvoted by some spammer, it's nothing personal with your code I guess :P

Comment: All answers except CodeCaster's.  Odd, that.  But as for this answer, you're not quoting your IDs.

Comment: @cHao: CodeCaster's was the only answer not offering a blatant SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @Boann: Ooo...there is that.  Heh...i'm usually the one bitching about those.  Dunno why i missed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM user_detail 
           WHERE user_id='".(intval) $array['userid'][0]."' 
           OR user_id='".(intval) $array['userid'][1]."'  
           OR user_id='".(intval) $array['userid'][2]."'";
```

Comment: The IDs aren't ints.  They appear to be hex values.